# Prevent prvalue from being bound to a variable

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a function that returns a temporary object which holds a reference inside and its sole purpose is to allow a sort of return-type overloading. For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class MyData {
private:
    class IntOrChar {
    public:
        IntOrChar(char const& c) : c_(c) {}
        operator char() { return c_; }
        operator int() { return c_-'0'; }
    private:
        char const& c_;
    };

public:
    MyData(std::string number) : number_(number) {}

    IntOrChar get(std::size_t i) { return number_[i]; }

private:
    std::string number_;
};

void accepts_char(char c) { std::cout << "char: " << c << '\n'; }
void accepts_int(int i) { std::cout << "int: " << i << '\n'; }

int main(){
    MyData n("012345");
    accepts_char(n.get(3));
    accepts_int(n.get(3));
}
```

The actual code is more complex, and the reference is to some internal state.

Using the above example, can I prevent the value returned from `get()` from being held on to? I want to prevent code like this:

```cpp
MyData n("0123");
auto r = n.get(2);
... // much later in the code
accepts_char(r);
```

since at the point where it is being used, the internal reference may no longer be valid. I want to force the casting class (`IntOrChar`) to be cast to a concrete type immediately and not held on to.

I think the terms I am looking for are that I want to prevent the prvalue from being turned into an xvalue?

I just want to prevent this from being done by accident. I don't care if it can be gotten around using some type of force-casting or other wizardry.

Comment: There's nothing in C++ for this. The most that can be done is to prevent a method from being called on a prvalue object, but no way to prohibit a prvalue from being saved.

Comment: _I have a function that returns a temporary object which holds a reference inside_ Hmmm, can't say I like that idea.  It's dangerous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround is to make the conversion functions **`&&`-qualified**.  Anyone who asks why they’re having to write `accepts_char(std::move(r))` can be reminded of the purpose of the type.

The real answer is to mark the type **lifetime-bound**, but that’s very much still a [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0936r0.pdf).  Another possibility for the exact example given would be to make `auto` fail for the type, but that’s also merely a [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0672r0.pdf).